# How to find out which Linux distribution I'm logged on to

Tags: linux

Is there a command for finding out the distribution of the OS I'm logged on to through SSH? `uname` can be used to print a whole lot of info, but apparently not the distribution (e.g. RedHat, Ubuntu etc.) nor the version of that distribution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am afraid, there is no standarized way to check it. Every distribution seems to have its own way of announcing its version. You may try: `cat /etc/*release`, it may work on a few systems. Also, `/etc/issue` may contain distribution information.

Comment: Thank you, both `cat /etc/*release` and `/etc/issue` give me the precise info I need.

Comment: On a base install of Debian (Lenny), /etc/*release doesn’t exist, but /etc/issue does (and has the right info).

Comment: This is one of the only solutions that has worked for me consistently.

Answer (score 8):

`lsb_release -a` *should* work on most distributions.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work on a base install of Debian (Lenny).

Comment: Looks like `lsb_release -i -s` works across most of the systems I have just to get the vendor ID. Unfortunately lsb_release is not part of the base install on my smaller / embedded systems, so it has to be tested for first.

Comment: @Dave It's in the `lsb-release` package, which, indeed, is not default. It's absence is a strong Debian indicator, though. :-)

Comment: Neither on OpenSuse.

Comment: `lsb_release` doesn't exist on some new RHEL6 derivatives, such as Scientific Linux 6.1 or Fedora Linux 16.

Answer (score 3):

lsb_release and more /etc/redhat-release for redhat and fedora i dont have idea about ubuntu and all other distro

Comment: lsb_release -a works on Ubuntu too.

Answer (score -1):

Generally /etc/motd gives the distribution name too...

Answer (score -2):

uname -o

The uname binary is found on almost every linux system and the -o flag does it's best to give you the operating system back. lsb_release works too but isn't quite as ubiquitous.

Comment: This fails on Ubuntu (lucid), however ubuntu has lsb_release, so first testing with `uname -o`, then if that comes back as just GNU/Linux, run `lsb_release -i -s` seems to work across all my systems.

Comment: This gives me "GNU/Linux" on RedHat, Debian and Ubuntu. On _what_ does it work?

Comment: GNU/Linux isn't very helpful. Most distros are GNU/linux ones.

Comment: @ychaouche: See comment above. First test with uname and if all you get is generic, test for lsb_release and use that.

Answer (score -3):

If you use the `-a` flag on `uname`, it should work most of the time.  For example, on my current Ubuntu machine `uname -a` prints:

`Linux clark-laptop 2.6.35-25-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 6 22:25:21 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`