# /etc/*release files examples

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, distribution

Where can I find a list of different `/etc/*release` files of various Linux/Unix/MacOS distributions and versions?

Same goes to `uname -a` command outputs.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why?

Comment: @JMeterX there's a subset of platforms and versions I need to identify programmatically after connecting to a remote machine.

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/119144/how-to-find-out-which-linux-distribution-im-logged-on-to

Comment: Install [facter](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/facter)?  Use its output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all systems have `/etc/*release*` files, so if you really want this to be cross-Unix you can't use them.

The POSIX-blessed solution is [`uname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/uname.html) -- If all you need is a coarse OS ID `uname -s`  will probably suffice.
I'm not aware of any canonical list of uname output, but [Wikipedia has a table that may be a good starting point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) (and presumably you have access to the platforms you're trying to detect so you can check what they return).

Sometimes `uname` doesn't tell the whole story (e.g. Linux distributions, which have substantial variability) - If it's necessary you can figure out more specific information (like "*Which* Linux distribution?") with a second pass that uses a system-specific tool (like `lsb_release` on Linux, or `oslevel` on AIX)

Comment: If you wind up using `uname` as part of your detection process it would be a kindness for the next poor soul who has to do this if you could update that Wikipedia article with the `uname` output from from operating systems which aren't listed :-)

Answer (score 4):

Most distributions have a tool called [`lsb_release`](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/lsbrelease.html).

Gentoo:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: Gentoo
Description:    Gentoo Base System release 2.0.3
Release:    2.0.3
Codename:   n/a
```

CentOS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
Release:    5.7
Codename:   Final
```

Other *nix distros: http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html

Comment: The only problem with `lsb` tools is they don't work on OS X, AIX, Solaris, any BSD system, HP-UX...

Comment: http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/misc/unix_commands.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from a C library I'm writing:

```c
const char* dist = dist_from_os_release();
if (strlen(dist) != 0)
    return dist;
else if (exists("/etc/arch-release"))
    return "arch";
else if (exists("/etc/altlinux-release"))
    return "altlinux";
else if (exists("/etc/angstrom-version"))
    return "angstrom";
else if (exists("/etc/annvix-release"))
    return "annvix";
else if (exists("/etc/arklinux-release"))
    return "arklinux";
else if (exists("/etc/aurox-release"))
    return "aurox";
else if (exists("/etc/blackcat-release"))
    return "blackcat";
else if (exists("/etc/cobalt-release"))
    return "cobalt";
else if (exists("/etc/conectiva-release"))
    return "conectiva";
else if (exists("/etc/debian_version") || exists("/etc/debian_release"))
    return "debian";
else if (exists("/etc/fedora-release"))
    return "fedora";
else if (exists("/etc/eos-version"))
    return "FreeEOS";
else if (exists("/etc/frugalware-release"))
    return "frugalware";
else if (exists("/etc/gentoo-release"))
    return "gentoo";
else if (exists("/etc/hlfs-release") || exists("/etc/hlfs_release"))
    return "HLFS";
else if (exists("/etc/immunix-release"))
    return "immunix";
else if (exists("knoppix_version"))
    return "knoppix";
else if (exists("/etc/lfs-release") || exists("/etc/lfs_version"))
    return "LFS";
else if (exists("/etc/linuxppc-release"))
    return "Linux-PPC";
else if (exists("/etc/mageia-release"))
    return "mageia";
else if (exists("/etc/mandrake-release"))
    return "mandrake";
else if (exists("/etc/mandriva-release") || exists("/etc/mandakelinux-release"))
    return "mandriva";
else if (exists("/etc/meego-release"))
    return "meego";
else if (exists("/etc/mklinux-release"))
    return "MkLinux";
else if (exists("/etc/nld-release"))
    return "Novell Linux Desktop";
else if (exists("/etc/pld-release"))
    return "PLD Linux";
else if (exists("/etc/redhat-release") || exists("/etc/redhat_version"))
    return "RHEL";
else if (exists("/etc/rubix-version"))
    return "rubix";
else if (exists("/etc/slackware-version") || exists("/etc/slackware-release"))
    return "slackware";
else if (exists("/etc/e-smith-release"))
    return "SME Server";
else if (exists("/etc/release"))
    return "Solaris SPARC";
else if (exists("/etc/sun-release"))
    return "Sun JDS";
else if (exists("/etc/SuSE-release") || exists("/etc/novell-release") || exists("/etc/sles-release"))
    return "SuSE";
else if (exists("/etc/synoinfo.conf"))
    return "Synology";
else if (exists("/etc/tinysofa-release"))
    return "tinysofa";
else if (exists("/etc/trustix-release") || exists("/etc/trustix-version"))
    return "trustix";
else if (exists("/etc/turbolinux-release"))
    return "TurboLinux";
else if (exists("/etc/ultrapenguin-release"))
    return "ultrapenguin";
else if (exists("/etc/UnitedLinux-release"))
    return "UnitedLinux";
else if (exists("/etc/va-release"))
    return "VA-Linux/RH-VALE";
else if (exists("/etc/yellowdog-release"))
    return "yellowdog";
else {
    struct utsname unameD;
    uname(&unameD);
    return strlen(unameD.nodename) > 0 ? unameD.nodename : unameD.sysname;
}
```

https://github.com/offscale/osbuild/commit/49200888e717907bb3dc36021f725b7e668274b7#diff-cc898028570115949c889ad5b8266020R34